# How to keep long running NHibernate Session data consistent?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, caching, consistency

I have NHibernate sessions cached in the ASP.NET session.

I came across a situation where a user edited an object so it's in their first level cache in the ISession. Another user then edited the same object.

At this point User1 still sees their original version of their edits where as User2 sees the correct state of the object?

What is the correct way to handle this without manually calling session.Refresh(myObj) explicitly for every single object all the time?

I also have a 2nd level cache enabled. For NHibernate Long Session should I just disable the first level cache entirely?

**Edit:** Adding some more terminology to what I'm looking to achieve from [10.4.1. Long session with automatic versioning](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#transactions-optimistic-longsession) the end of this section concludes with

> As the ISession is also the (mandatory) first-level cache and contains all loaded objects, we can propably use this strategy only for a few request/response cycles. This is indeed recommended, as the ISession will soon also have stale data.

I'm not sure what kind of documentation this is for it to include both probably and then immediately say the session will have stale data (which is what I'm seeing). What's the solution to this right here or is there none?

Comment: The correct way is not using long running sessions. Why do you do that?

Comment: That's an inaccurate statement. The long running session is a perfectly valid session management pattern. Unfortunately it's seems to be inordinately more complex than session per request.

Comment: Paco is right, you do not get what ISession is used for

Comment: Sigh, it's not a good start to a question for 2 people to already be posting inaccurate statements to it.

Comment: From official nHibernate doc: 
A single-threaded, short-lived object representing a conversation between the application and the persistent store. Wraps an ADO.NET connection. Factory for ITransaction. Holds a mandatory (first-level) cache of persistent objects, used when navigating the object graph or looking up objects by identifier.

Comment: Chris, please... That's nHibernate 101.http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-2-architecture/1nr4enxv3dpeq/6#

Comment: Pierre I'm talking about applications that are far far past NHibernate 101.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a known shortcoming of NHibernate as detailed by documentation cited in my question.

Comment: Chris Marisic, did Optimistic Concurrency answer your question? Assuming you came across the problem in the following question, could you answer it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72176820/can-nhibernate-long-session-pattern-have-multiple-transactions-that-update-dat

Comment: @SocialDeveloper I abandoned attempting to use long transactions with nhibernate entirely. I abandoned nhibernate for Linq2Sql and then l2s to move on to Dapper.

Answer (score 3):

- You can't disable the first-level cache.
- Check out "[Optimistic concurrency control](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#transactions-optimistic)" in the NHibernate docs.
- Also take a look at [NHibernate.Burrow](http://nhforge.org/wikis/burrow/introduction.aspx) for long conversations.

Comment: Added information in regards to your link to optimistic concurrency control.

Answer (score 3):

Just use IStatelessSession instead of ISession.

Also keep in mind that NH wasn't designed to be used with long-living ISessions (as already mentioned by others). One problem is that you already mentioned. The other is that the performance drops significantly when there's a large object graph tracked by NH. Both problems could be avoided by using IStatelesSession. 
It gives you detached objects not being tracked by NH.

Not sure about the reasoning behind keeping sessions in the ASP.NET session. Maybe you could provide some details?

Also remember that a session is a wrapper over IDbConnection. Keeping it open can easily lead to conneciton pool starvation.

Comment: Does the IStateless use the 2nd level cache? I can't seem to find any definitive answer from google.

Comment: But if I'm using IStateless it's pointless to even manage session at all.

Comment: Stateless session doesn't interact with any second-level cache.

Comment: Well managing sessions (as in your scenario) doesn't have much sense for me whatever the case. You can use regular or statless session, close it when get request ends, then when user posts a form, you copy values from post request to object fetched with newly opened session (not stateless) first checking if the DB version (optimistic control) is not higher than the one passed from form.

Comment: I want the long running session pattern to be able to correctly handle wizard interfaces so if a user abandons their wizard it just destroys the data instead of leaving half completed data in my database. So yes I do correctly need the 1st level cache. Which my implementation handles fine, it's when 2 users have different versions of the same object in their first level cache it breaks down. This really seems like a shortcoming of NHibernate that there should be an option for ISessions to use 1st level cache only for transient objects and to disable it for non-transient.